# DOCX: Field code that evaluates to empty string as field result

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I need to insert the field in the word document which ultimately evaluates to empty string.

Some ideas I've;

```
- Set intersection: both sets have nothing in common and finally field result would lead to empty.
- "".concats(""), leads to ""
```

Can we insert such kind of field code in office word document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to insert a field with an empty string as the result you could use a `MACROBUTTON` field with no caption that points to a non-existing macro:

```
{ MACROBUTTON NoMacro }
```

Using the OpenXML SDK, you can create such a button like this:

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph(
    new Run(new FieldChar { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin }),
    new Run(new FieldCode { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve, 
                            Text = " Macrobutton NoMacro " }),
    new Run(new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End }));
```

Comment: I've not found the NoMacro part in MS word 13, however using the idea ' MACROBUTTON  nonpublic ' could work. I just want to insert this field in certain situations (first run node in first paragraph is text box) - not aware about cases suitable for MACROBUTTON field. This would be visible to end user of the word document. So, just curious if its legal (very hard word, sorry for that) to use MACROBUTTON, or is there some other field type we can use in situation (first run being text box)?

Comment: @Prakhar: NoMacro is just a dummy name of a macro that does not exist. You can put any text there you like unless it is the name of an existing macro or built-in Word command. And it certainly is legal to have a macro button field anywhere where you can have a field.